# Creating a new class and calling the class from data pulled from database

Tags: php, class

I have a class called page, it pulls all the data from the database for the current page.  When the current page information is loaded, I need to call the new class and show the show body function from the page's class.  Example code...

```
<?php
//page class
class Page{

    var $p;
    var $pageline = array();

    function __construct(){
        global $_GET;

        if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
            $this->p = 'home';
        }
        else{
            $this->p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
            $sql = "select * from pages where friendurl = '{$this->p}'";
            if(mysql_query($sql)){
                $page = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
                $this->p = $page['id'];
                foreach($page as $key => $val){
                    if(!is_int($key)){
                        $this->pageline[$key] = $val;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }           
        }
    }

}
?>
```

So I have the var $pageline full of all the information from the database for the current page we are on.  I have a coloumn called pageClass

On the home page, I need to call that class and call the function showBody.

I tried this, and also tried other ways but was unable to figure it out.

```
<?php
$bodyClass = $Page->pageline['friendurl'];
//echo $bodyClass;
$bodyClass->showBody();

?>
```

This is the error I keep getting!
**Fatal error: Call to a member function showBody() on a non-object in ***************** on line 136**

It is a function and it is an object

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I see no `showBody()` method, try adding it to the class and then using `$Page->showBody();`

Comment: It is not going to show in the $Page class the friendurl is actually a name of a class already called and started

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a scope for your properties like `public`, `private` or `protected`.
2. Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore because they're deprecated. Use [`PDO`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
3. Don't load your page data in the constructor. Make a class `Page` which contains just the page data and some page logic and make a class `PageModel` which loads data from the DB and generates an instance of `Page`.
4. You call a method `showBody()` which is not defined in your class `Page`.